# TV movie: people travel back in time to see disasters

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel, tv

This was maybe late 90's, early 2000's- A man is photographed in a subway train wreck (I think)- later he is found in pictures of multiple disasters that happened years or even decades earlier. Turns out he is a morbid sort of tourist from the future, who pays to be sent to catastrophes occurring in the past to witness them himself. A modern woman who learns of this sort of tourist industry is appalled that people would use time travel this way.

Comment: I can't remember the plot well enough to say it's a match, but it could also be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timescape_(film) a.k.a "The Grand Tour: Disasters in Time"

Comment: Definitely not *Timescape*, though the theme is the same.

Answer (score 6):

I googled the phrase "time travel disaster tourist movie" and the second hit is for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrill_Seekers_(film) which seems to match your description.